# How to plot symbolic graph on top of normal plot in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I've managed to plot on normal graph using the plot function in matlab. I then generated a symbolic function and I managed to plot that using ezplot. I would like to plot the two graphs into one set of x,y axis. I'm not sure how to do this... Here is the code:

```
a = [50; 100; 150;200;250;300;350];
b = [56;23;22;18;14;15;21];

plot(a,b);

y = polyfit(a,b,2);
syms x;
f = y(1)*x^2 + y(2)*x + y(3);
g = diff(f);
u = solve(g);
subplot(2, 2, 2);
ezplot(f);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you familiar with the hold command?

[hold command](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hold.html)